# React doesn't render but no errors in console

Tags: reactjs

Trying to render a hello world but nothing is displayed on the page. There are no messages displayed in the console. What am I missing here? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.js"></script>
        <scriptt src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js."></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <!-- Signal to babel that we would like it to handle the execution of the JS inside this script tag -->
        <script type="text/babel">

            class App extends React.Component {
                render() {
                    return <h1>Hello from our app</h1>
                }
            }

            var mount = document.querySelector('#app');

            ReactDom.render(<App />, mount);
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding  dukenicols but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that it is ReactDOM not ReactDom

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello from our app</h1>
  }
}

var mount = document.querySelector('#app');

ReactDOM.render(<App />, mount);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```